# Scroll LinkedHashMap to key

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

How do I scroll a `LinkedHashMap` to a specific key? Something like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> queque = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
queque.put("uno","uno");
queque.put("due","due");
queque.put("tre","tre");
queque.put("quattro","quattro");
queque.put("cinque","cinque");
Iterator i = queque.entrySet().iterator();
while(i.next().getKey().equals(quattro)) {
    System.out.print(i.getKey() + ": ");
    System.out.println(i.getValue());
    i.next();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong about your current approach (besides that there are syntax errors and you didn't read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java yet)?

Comment: does not work,eclipse suggests to me a cast in the iterator , but how?

Comment: As per your last edit: you probably want `while(!i.next().getKey().equals(quattro))` instead because with the  condition you have now you will only print entry for "quattro".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly iterate (unless you really want to) to get the value by key: just use `get()` method:

```
System.out.println("quattro" + ": " + queque.get("quattro"));
```

If you want to print all the values up to the certain one, you can do the following:

```
Iterator i = queque.entrySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> me = i.next();
        if (me.getKey() == "quattro") break;
        System.out.println(me.getKey() + ": " + me.getValue());
    }
```

Or, a little more elegant:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> me : queque.entrySet()) {
    if (me.getKey() == "quattro") break;
    System.out.println(me.getKey() + ": " + me.getValue());
}
```

Couple more points:

1. If you do not need to store the elements in the order they were added, use `HashMap` rather than `LinkedHashMap`, since former is faster. If you want store elements sorted, use `TreeMap`(but beware it is slower than the other types of `Map`).
2. When you create instance of container in Java, you are better off using *interface* (like `Map`, `List` or `Set`) in the left part of assignment and *implementation* (like `HashMap`, `ArrayList` etc.) in the right part since it gives you much more flexibility: in case you later on decide to change the implementation of the same interface (e.g. use `HashMap` instead of `LinkedHashMap` as I suggested above), you only need to change one line of your code where you create this container, rather than change all places where this container is used.

Comment: I want to print the list up to a specific value , not print a single value

Comment: @alexander That is crucial information which should be part of your question.

Comment: String me = i.next(); in this line i have an error of mismatch.

Comment: @alexander: If you're satisfied with the answer, would you consider accepting it? Thanks!

Comment: @alexander: So can you accept it then? (Seeing you're new here, a quick explanation just in case: it's the custom here at StackOverflow to "accept" the answer which the question author has found the most useful. Such accepted answer is marked by green tick-mark and shows up at the very top, right below the answer.) Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok sorry I did not realize , now okay?

Comment: @alexander: Yeah, thanks! You might want to do the same thing to your other question threads too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it right with `Iterator` you would do

```
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> i = queque.entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> entry = i.next();
        if ("quattro".equals(entry.getKey()))
            break;
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

But that is equivalent to using an enhanced for loop like so:

```
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : queque.entrySet()) {
        if ("quattro".equals(entry.getKey()))
            break;
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

with `Iterator` you'll have to check `hasNext()`, only then call `next()` once(!) per loop or your iterator would advance by two elements. You should also never compare `String`s with `==`, that's just not working.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using `TreeMap` to me. Then you just use [`TreeMap.headMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#headMap(K)).